# All map handle the same file?

Tags: hadoop

Usually Hadoop split the file and send every split to each machine, but I want to let each machine handle the same file(not a split of the file), and then send the result to reduce,and in reduce process it sums all the result. How can I do this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is your aim by doing that? It doesn't look like a mapreduce problem at the first sight.

Comment: I want to use it for a random sampling,because it has many iterations,so is not good to split. so I want to let each machine do some sampling and then sum the result.

Comment: I am not sure if I can use the distributedcache do this? If the file was stored in distributed cache, then each machine can read, but there is no other input file(not in distributed ache),so how can the job start?

Comment: Your problem doesn't sound like a mapreduce problem after you've described it. Why do you want to use hadoop? Is it an obligation?

Comment: Yes,it is a obligation

Comment: What prevents *all* mappers from generating the same samples? Sounds to me that the input of your job is not the file, but the sampling technique. Write a custom [`InputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. This may not be the exact solution , but a dirty way to achieve this is :
set `FileInputFormat.setMaxInputSplitSize(job, size)` where value of size parameter must be greater than  input file size in bytes which can be calculated using `length()` method of java `File` class. It ensures that there will be only one mapper per file and your fie doesn't get split. 
Now use `MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, input_path, InputFormat.class)` for each of your machines which will run single mapper on each of the machine . 
And as per your requirement reduce function  don't require  any changes.
 **Dirty part** here is - that `MultipleInputs.addInputPath` requires unique path . So, you may have to copy the same file to no of times the no of mappers you want and give them unique names and supply it to parameter of `MultipleInputs.addInputPath`. If you provide the same path, it will be ignored.

Comment: Well, dirty part is dirtier than you think. Mapreduce is to process big data efficiently. So you cannot even assume that you have enough space to make several copies of the same data. In a typical scenario you have data in the order or gigabytes.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı ..yes, the solution is dirty and not for very big scale data. But, in real life , not enough companies who use hadoop for batch processing process peta-scale of data, which hadoop is capable of. And distcp-ing some gb of data doesn't take time. You can always write a script which will delete additional copies. All said, obviously this solution is bad, but this came first to my mind , so i wrote it. Better solutions are always welcome.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have also a question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have also a question. Is it possible, if I store the file in distributedcache, and I write a custom inputformat, in which tell hadoop that, there is no inputpath, mapper should handle the file in distributedcache?

Comment: Distributed cache was never meant for big data files. If you do this for big size files, you better check your cluster configurations. And the methods you suggested is quite feasible, you just put files in distributed cache, it will be copied to all of the slave nodes, and you can do map operations. But, I fear, nobody will suggest you to so. It just won't scale..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have more than one problem. What (I think) you want to do:

- Produce some set of random samples
- Sum sample

I'd just break these down into two separate, simple maps / reduces. A mapreduce to produce the random samples. A second to sum each sample separately.

Now there's probably a clever way to do this all in one pass, but unless you've got some unusual constraints, I'd be surprised if it was worth the extra complexity.